# Where can I find an example of a C++ ROS 2 rqt plugin?

Tags: ros2, c++, rqt

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So far, I've only found ROS 2 rqt plugins ported over from ROS 1 that were written in Python. The docs (https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Concepts/About-RQt.html) mention writing custom plugins in both Python and C++, and I also see that rqt_gui_cpp exists on the rolling branch of the rqt github repos. I haven't been able to get a C++ rqt plugin build to work correctly without an example to work off of.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/414984/where-can-i-find-an-example-of-a-c++-ros-2-rqt-plugin?/) by [Tupinambis](https://answers.ros.org/users/147527/tupinambis/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2023-05-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

One of the "core" rqt tools, `rqt_image_view` is mainly C++, then [rolling-devel](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_image_view/tree/rolling-devel) branch seems to be ROS2-tified (interestingly `humble-devel` branch, likely the branch for the latest released ROS2, still uses Catkin so not fully ROS2 yet).

**UPDATE** Apparently for [some/many ROS2 releases, rqt_image_view has already been released (index.ros.org)](https://index.ros.org/search/?term=rqt_image_view) so the branch may be of little concern even though some are still using Catkin as the build system at the time of writing). Try `humble-devel`? If you still see issues you should report at [the repository](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rqt_image_view/issues).

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2023-05-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tupinambis](https://answers.ros.org/users/147527/tupinambis/) on 2023-05-10**:
Thanks, I believe this is just what I was looking for!

**Comment by [Tupinambis](https://answers.ros.org/users/147527/tupinambis/) on 2023-05-10**:
When running this plugin I get the following log messages:

munmap_chunk(): invalid pointer

Everything I've found related to this refers to misuse of alloc functions which aren't used anywhere in the plugin codebase. Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong?

**Comment by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on 2023-05-10**:
@Tupinambis I've updated my post.

**Comment by [Tupinambis](https://answers.ros.org/users/147527/tupinambis/) on 2023-05-10**:
After starting off from a fresh rolling container that error no longer occurs. I wish I could say what the root cause is, but oh well. Thanks again for your help.